# how to have more than 1 container using jquery masonry

Tags: jquery-masonry

I have a tabs set up on my website and I would like to use Masonry on the content of each tab, but I can only get it working on 1 tab at a time.

Initially I tried just using the generic  selector and using that in each tab. This however just worked in the first tab. I then tried adding more container variables:

```
<!--Masonry kit-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/LazyDuck/masonry-site/js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).load(function() {

var $container = $('#container');
var $container = $('#dining');
var $container = $('#events');
var $container = $('#climbing');
var $container = $('#wildlife');
var $container = $('#shopping');
var $container = $('#kids');
var $container = $('#sport');


$container.masonry({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  gutterWidth : 10,
  isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
});
});});
```

But that doesn't work either. I'm sure this is a simple thing but my JavaScript coding isn't so great. I guessed the above. :(

Comment: I think this goes some way to explaining how to do it.

https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/161

Although I am going to be using this many times over, so I wonder if there is any way of reducing the superfluous code generated.

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers,

ali

Comment: The above comment works to a certain extent.

Comment: The above comment works to a certain extent.

I am still having problems with the tabs. Although now I can create the differnt containers masonry only works on the initially loaded tab. If you click another tab the divs are loaded ontop of each other, although if you resize the browser window it triggers the masonry JQuery and the divs slide into place.

Any help would be fantastic. It's driving me insane!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more of jQUery syntax but also i think masonry wont work if there is no visible content. It has to be applied to a div that is visible.

So one way would be to do it all while its visible and then hide it.. Not great.. I know.

```
var $container = $('#container');
var $container = $('#dining');
var $container = $('#events');
var $container = $('#climbing');
var $container = $('#wildlife');
```

To solve the chainablilty of starting the plugin just do this

```
$('#wildlife, #climbing , ... ,#container).masonry({ ..
```

But in this case it would be easier to toggle it by a uniqe class name such as

```
class="MasoniseThis otherClasses"
...
$('.MasoniseThis').masonry({ ..
```

And on each pageload it should apply the plugin to any visible divs with that Class on it.

*Without some markupor example in JSFiddle we cannot really help you any more.*